# Is there any way to reduce this code?

Tags: c++

Use for loop to reduce it, I believe, but I don't know how.

Is there any way to reduce this code?

```
    num1 = 1, num2 = 2, num3 = 3;
    display(num1, num2, num3);

    num1 = 1, num2 = 3, num3 = 2;
    display(num1, num2, num3);

    num1 = 2, num2 = 1, num3 = 3;
    display(num1, num2, num3);

    num1 = 2, num2 = 3, num3 = 1;
    display(num1, num2, num3);

    num1 = 3, num2 = 1, num3 = 2;
    display(num1, num2, num3);

    num1 = 3, num2 = 2, num3 = 1;
    display(num1, num2, num3);
```

Comment: What language? Java and C++ are very different.

Comment: I use C++, if you would like Java, it's fine.

Comment: @symta Will it always and forever be 3 numbers and 3 parameters?  Will the sequence always and forever start from 1 increment by 1?   I say "forever", since you don't want to code yourself into a corner with a solution that isn't scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, or in C++, you could use an array of arrays. In Java 8+ like,

```
int[][] nums = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 3, 2 }, { 2, 1, 3 }, { 2, 3, 1 }, 
        { 3, 1, 2 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };
Stream.of(nums).forEachOrdered(x -> display(x[0], x[1], x[2]));
```

**or** in C++ like

```
int nums[6][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 3, 2 }, { 2, 1, 3 }, { 2, 3, 1 }, 
        { 3, 1, 2 }, { 3, 2, 1 } };
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        display(nums[i][0], nums[i][1], nums[i][2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the c++ function next_permutation() to get all permutations of [1, 2, 3], the code is very simple, like this

```
int num[3] = {1, 2, 3};
do
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << num[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
} while (next_permutation(num, num + 3));
```

More about permutation you can see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Comment: I have the feeling this will not show the first permutation, and it will not show all 6 permutations.

Comment: you are right, I didn't test this code.

Answer (score 0):

Without extra information as to what you're trying to achieve this is difficult to answer, I'd implement a function if I were using C++ that looks like this

```
void foo(int x, int y, int z)
{
    cout << x << y << z;
}

void main
{
    foo(1,2,3);
    foo(2,1,3);
}
```

would be one way to make the code more manageable... this depends on what you're trying to achieve though.

or consider replacing foo with the following

```
foo(int x, int y, int z)
{
    cout << x << y << z;
    cout << x << z << y;
    cout << z << x << y;
    cout << z << y << x;
    cout << y << z << x;
    cout << y << x << z;
}
```